# Prove that points O, P, Q are collinear

Tags: geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be an acute triangle, with $O$ as its circumcenter. $H$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ to the line $BC$, and points $P$ and $Q$ are the feet of the perpendiculars from $H$ to the lines $AB$ and $AC$, respectively.

> Given that, 
>   $$AH^2=2\cdot AO^2$$
>   prove that the points $O,P,Q$ are collinear.

Comment: Doesn't this given mean that triangle $AHO$ is a right isosceless triangle at $O$? If you please upload a figure to your question, this will help you get more answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do an [inversion](https://imomath.com/index.php?options=323&lmm=0) centered at $A$ with radius $AH$. The image of $P$ is $B$ and the image of $Q$ is $C$. Denote by $O'$ the image of $O$ under that inversion. Since $AH^2 = AO \cdot 2AO$, we get $AO' = 2AO$, that is, $AO'$  is the diameter of the circumcircle of $ABC$. Since $A, B, C$ and $O'$ lie on a circle passing through the center of inversion, the images of $B, C$ and $O'$ lie on a line. These images are $P, Q$ and $O$.

Comment: Beautiful... +1

Comment: Really nice application of *inversion*! [+1]